# changing url structure with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

For a new site we are developing, the URL structure is as follows.

- http://sitename.com/index.php?video=id/id2   (ids are numeric)
- http://sitename.com/index.php?aboutus

After everything is finished, now the *client wants to change the URL structure as follows

- http://sitename.com/video/id/id2
- http://sitename.com/aboutus

How can i change this as per his requirements with mod_rewrite / htaccess? I am not an expert with htaccess and its not possible for us to change the platform now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1?$2/$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*?)/?$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?$1=$2/$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule (.*?)/?$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

### htaccess example

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # About Us ---------------------------------------
    RewriteRule ^aboutus.html*$ index.php?page=aboutus [L]

</IfModule>
```

### mod rewrite php example

```
function replace_for_mod_rewrite($s) {
$siteUrl = "Your site url";
$urlin = array( "`".$siteUrl."/index\.php\?page=aboutus(['|\"|#])`is" );
$urlout = array( $siteUrl."/aboutus.html\\1" );
$s = preg_replace($urlin, $urlout, $s);
}
```

More Details : [TechNew.In](http://www.technew.in/)